# What's the simplest high voltage AC square wave oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, high-voltage, square

I'd like to have such an AC square wave oscillator putting AC through a load - which can go to 60 VDC and deliver no more than 50 mA with sharp, fast rise times and very "square". I would hope a topology exists.

The biggest request/demand I have is a circuit which would use the least amount of components, *especially* ICs if there would be any ICs then please a topology with ICs that have the least amount of pins. In other words, I am looking for an oscillator which can be thrown together onto a breadboard rather quickly. I need an actual circuit, not an output from a function generator.

**Frequency:** 3.9 Hz **Duty:** 50% **Load:** Resistive, no smaller than 1 kΩ

Squareness, sharp and fast rise times are just desires. I'm sure people won't suggest an oscillator which is slow enough to turn a square into a triangle wave.

Comment: Frequency, duty cycle, and quantification of "sharp, fast" will be needed. Also some idea of the input characteristic of the load.

Comment: Just added specifics you mentioned.

Comment: In that case, a 555 timer driving a MOSFET should do the trick.

Comment: Thats not going to make AC into load.

Comment: You said you wanted square waves with 60 Vdc pk-to-pk. Where's the AC involved?

Comment: Read title it blatantly states "asymmetric"

Comment: @user9762541 "asymmetric" means duty cycle != 50%. AC can mean with, or without DC. Given these, could you draw using your favourite drawing program an example of how the wave would look like? If you could include a dashed/dotted/etc line as the DC level, that would be great. Otherwise, I'd suggest an NPN [astable](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html), followed by some MOS for 60V.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thanks - that's a rather less annoyed version of what I was in the middle of writing..!

Comment: Updated title, I guess I thought asymmetric meant AC  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJK3G.jpg notice how it crosses baseline.

Comment: This appears to be a "free design service" question with no attempt at research or a solution.

Comment: You can build one with a relay and a capacitor. Doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is a blocking  oscillator, using one transformer, 
a transistor, and a power source (battery?) with a couple of
passive components.
The frequency isn't easy to adjust, the transformer has to be 
customized for the power input and desired output voltage, but it
IS simple.
 [typical blocking oscillator](http://www.interfacebus.com/transistor-blocking-oscillator-circuit.html)
If your output doesn't share a negative or positive rail with the
input power source, a three-winding transformer is used.

While it is simple (in the sense of component count) the design
is subtle and depends on magnetic nonlinearity in the transformer.
It isn't flexible, or inexpensive, in a one-off (because of the
customized transformer).   If you want symmetric square waves,
a two-transistor variant is a possible improvement.

A high-voltage-capable op amp with three resistors and capacitor
is a more common  solution, but 50 mA and 60V are higher power
than most such amplifiers offer.

Comment: This is probably a rather bad answer. The thing is, it's really hard to get a transformer which works at 3.9 Hz.

Answer (score -1):

Suggest using a Colpitt's or Hartley oscillator fed into a CMOS inverter.

Comment: Can you explain how the OP will get 60 V AC (that's +60 V to -60 V) at 50 mA from a CMOS inverter?

Comment: I don't think the 50ma constraint was on the supply.  OP?